# swfupload and setting request headers

Tags: javascript, swfupload

I use swfupload in my JS and works generally fine. The problem is that i can't pass any additional headers (such as basic authorization header), because swfupload uses Filereference instead of URLLoader to send the data.

Is there any workaround for adding request headers to Filereference objects? 
Or maybe there are other versions of swfupload that use URLLoader?

Answer (score 0):

maybe is late, but do you try with post_params?:

```
var settings = {
                flash_url: "/swf/swfupload.swf",
                upload_url: "upload.aspx",
                post_params: { "param1": "your param" }
};
```

or this is not wath you are asking?